# Uploading and debugging an app located in /Applications folder

Tags: iphone, xcode, debugging, ios5, permissions

Is there a way to upload my app to iPhone's /Applications folder instead of /private/var/mobile/Applications inside Xcode and debug it?

Thanks!

Comment: you want to install your iPhone app into your "`/Applications/`" folder on your development Macintosh???

Comment: No, in /Applications folder on my iDevice

Comment: is this for an appstore app or jailbreak?

Comment: jailbreak......actually, I am currently just testing things.. I need a way to debug an app in /Applications folder in the iPhone, because it is crashing

Comment: Anyone knows? I really need it urgently.. thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I guess the only way to debug application not from sandbox, is by using Console.